# What is the word for or a psychological term for person who knows how to do a job but says he does not know because he does not want to work?

Tags: single-word-requests, psychology

If I am assigned a work and i know how to do it but I will say i do not know because I do not want to work.

Comment: Why would there be a psychological term? Isn't "liar" accurate enough?

Comment: Of course one must consider motivation -- how many people, when asked to clean a dirty bathroom, would claim that they didn't know how to do it?

Comment: (It's often called "shirking'.)

Comment: @HotLicks I was thinking "lazy bastard"

Comment: POB.  One might call them "lazy", "liar", "irresponsible", "unconcerned", "happy-go-lucky", "unhelpful" but none of these are specific for "knows but doesn't want"

Answer (score 0):

The (more general) term *incongruence* (**incongruent person** here) comes to mind. It is the opposite of *congruence* defined as '**matching of experience and awareness**'.

https://study.com/academy/lesson/incongruence-in-psychology-definition-lesson-quiz.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say

"**A work-shy person"**.

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work-shy?topic=laziness-and-lazy-people) :

***Work-shy***

adjective

​
- disliking work and trying to avoid it when possible:

// Most of the unemployed are not work-shy and genuinely do want jobs.

One more word which can be appropriate here:

***Malingerer***

from the verb

***[to malinger](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malingerer)***

intransitive verb

: to ***pretend*** or exaggerate  ***incapacity*** or illness  (as to avoid duty or work)

[Or](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/malinger):

: to ***pretend*** to be ill or otherwise  ***incapacitated*** in order to escape duty or work; shirk

Answer (score 0):

If they choose to say they don't know how to do it, it's because they have no real escuse except that they are lazy and unconcerned.  In such context I would use these two adjectives.

> - [**lazy**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lazy) Not willing to work or be energetic,
> - [**unconcerned**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconcerned) (not involved : not having any part or interest) **suggests a lack of sensitivity or regard for others' needs or troubles.**